# How to transform selected element into transparent object

Tags: templates, background, transparency, blogger

I'm currently developing my blogspot, and want to make it look a little better. How can I make these white boxes disappear, so the text could only be visible?

https://gyazo.com/4635706ee7e157776ac3a584073ddd01
These are the boxes that I'm talking about. I'm very poor at this, and don't know how to make it.

I don't know how to edit HTML code either. I tried once pasting this:

```
<div class='blog-posts hfeed'>
{ padding: $(content.padding) $(content.padding.horizontal); opacity: 0; filter:alpha(opacity=0); }
```

...but it only left a gray text quoting the same thing I put there on the main page.

I expect all the white squares to fade away and have only text on the site along with images.